# MySQL Login / Logout Audit

Tags: mysql, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I need to know when users log in and log out to the mysql database.

My first attempt was to set the parameters **general_log** and **log_output** = FILE. However these options generate excessive logs and this is a problem for me. In fact I do not need to know which queries were executed; just need to know who, when and where (IP) users have logged in and logged out.

My second attempt was to configure the **performance_schema** parameter. But it also was not possible because the database is a Cloud SQL and the instance I use does not support this configuration and we can not increase the power of the instance in google cloud.

Is there another way to get all user login / logout in mysql? Including also failed login attempts.

The database version is MySQL 5.7.

Just reinforcing my question. I'm not interested in knowing the logins from the application. I am concerned about the logins in MySQL. Login from any client.

Example: From Workbrand, MySql Client, etc.

Comment: Does MySQL actually log this?

Comment: Er, are you *sure* you're concerned about logins to *MySQL*?  Oftentimes people come here asking questions like this, but it turns out they're actually concerned about logins to *their application* (with their application then connecting to MySQL in turn, but that's of far less interest).

Comment: (As far as this *is* a MySQL question,) This question is at the very border of what is or isn't [on topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): see point `5. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.` - *is* a standard-conforming DB *used primarily for programming*? Is it it for your users? Is it for you during development? The question [*may* be on-topic elsewhere](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to query Mysql login logs is through the general logs.

However you can still get the the failed login attempt by running the following command:

gcloud logging read "Access denied for user" | grep -B 5 textPayload | grep -Ev 'project_id|region|type|severity'